# Is possible to install a .exe assembly into the GAC?

Tags: c#, dll, exe, .net-assembly, gac

When I read about GAC installation, I saw that is not possible to install exe assemblies into GAC. But, examining my PC GAC folder I found an exe, named `dfsvc.exe`.

Do you know why? Is really impossible to install exe assemblies in that folder?

[image: This is the book part]

[image: this is my exe in the GAC]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79(v=vs.110).aspx Read gacutil.exe way.

Comment: Why would you want to register an executable in the GAC? How are you going to start it?

Comment: I used gacutil, but the doubt is about possible or not to install .exe assemblies. @Nikhil

Comment: Is academic doubt, I dont want to install .exe in gac. But I've one in my GAC folder. @CodeCaster

Comment: @CodeCaster -- Executables with public APIs can be referenced just like DLLs.  So, while you wouldn't execute it from the GAC, it might make sense to reference it from there.

Comment: @johnny5 -- First of all, an executable *is* an assembly.   Secondly, see my previous comment.

Comment: @johnny5 ??? Why do you think .Net exe is not an assembly? (Obviously regular Win32 exe is not one)

Comment: @rory.ap is right. Exe is an assembly. But it is executable.

Comment: It is a plumbing file for ClickOnce apps, System.Deployment.dll uses it in its ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker() method.  it takes care of downloading updates for the app, that kind of stuff.  Don't mess with it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to store a .NET executable, which is an assembly, into the GAC. You use `gacutil -i path\to\assembly.exe` using an elevated command shell. Make sure you have strong signed the executable.

As Hans mentions in the comments, `dfsvc.exe` is related to *ClickOnce*. I'm guessing that executable exposes APIs, and that's why it's registered. Maybe they didn't want to separate API from EXE to minimize the footprint (e.g. they didn't want the EXE one place and a DLL in the GAC).

Also, it is possible to run the EXE. Just change to the subdirectory of `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly` where the program is, and run it (assuming you don't need a `.exe.config` file, which of course can't be installed in the GAC!